# Get AppName in sdk

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, bundle

How should I get the name of the application from the library where the library using on that particular application. Already, I have tried with CFBundelName and CFBundleDisplayName but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **kCFBundleNameKey**? (used since Swift 3)

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
```

**Swift 4:**

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
```

Comment: Both of these methods are available as of Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in one of my projects working in an SDK:

```
var appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: No, its not working @Enrique Bermúdez

Comment: Ok, clearly we will need more information about your problem. As I said that code works completely fine in a static library that I have worked on.